# How to subtract bigger number to small

Tags: bash

How to subtract bigger number to small in bash script.
What I've tried is
Ex:

```
  jiraTotalValue=$(($jiraIssueTotal - $jiraIssueMetric))
```

which jiraIssueTotal has a value of 3 and jiraIssueMetrics has a value of 2.

when I'm running my command it says

```
./test.sh: line 12: 3 - 2
0: syntax error in expression (error token is "0")
```

Comment: How do you set the variables `jiraIssueTotal` and `jiraIssueMetric`?

Comment: What do you get if you add this line before: `printf "$jiraIssueTotal $jiraIssueMetric" | hexdump -c`

Comment: Thanks for Replying.
I've Fixed it already by trying
`let jiraTotalValue=$jiraIssueTotal-$jiraIssueMetric`

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `let`. The line you show is fine, which makes me think that's not the exact line you were running to produce that error.

Answer (score 0):

This should not cause any problems, maybe it's an issue of your editor
I have tested on:

```
a=3;
b=2;
c=$(($a - $b));
echo "$c";
```

It prints "1", the result is correct.